# Index In Google Anlytics's Enhanced Ecommerce Event 'view_item_list' not flowing

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-datalayer, enhanced-ecommerce

I am passing the index as number for GA that is getting captured in item_list_index field of GA in Web.
But same thing is not flowing for Android.
Getting not set.

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events?client_type=gtag#view_item_list

I tried changing the type from number to string but that is also not working.